# How to write a "thread safe" function in C?

Tags: c, thread-safety

Hello I am writing some data structures in C, and I've realized that their associated functions aren't thread safe. The i am writing code uses only standard C, and I want to achieve some sort of 'synchronization'.

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
enum sync_e { TRUE, FALSE };
typedef enum sync_e sync;


struct list_s {
//Other stuff
    struct list_node_s *head;
    struct list_node_s *tail;
    enum sync_e locked;
};
typedef struct list_s list;
```

, to include a "boolean" field in the list structure that indicates the structures state: locked, unlocked.

For example an insertion function will be rewritten this way:

```
int list_insert_next(list* l, list_node *e, int x){
    while(l->locked == TRUE){
        /* Wait */
    }
    l->locked = TRUE;
    /* Insert element */
    /* -------------- */
    l->locked = FALSE;
    return (0);
}
```

While operating on the list the 'locked' field will be set to TRUE, not allowing any other alterations. After operation completes the 'locked' field will be again set to 'TRUE'.

Is this approach good ? Do you know other approaches (using only **standard** C).

Comment: How are you making threads using only standard C?  There must be some synchronization primitives built into such a system, but I don't know how you do a context switch without writing some assembly code.

Comment: Creating threads is not my scope. I just want to "protect" my structure.

Comment: @Andrei, if you don't have threads, you don't need to protect it.  If you do have threads, the threading library must by necessity provide features that allow you to protect it.

Comment: So I should concentrate on the functionality of the structure, and leave the synchronization process in the hands of the programmer who reuse the code in a threaded environment.

Comment: @Andrei, if you don't know what kind of synchronization primitives the other programmer might have, there's no way you can solve the problem by just using C.  You need processor or OS support to get the atomic operations you must have to make safe multithreaded code.

Comment: @Andrei: further to what Carl says, in most languages you can write a self-synchronizing data structure, because the language defines the threading model and the synchronization. So for instance in Java you can just write `synchronized` methods (although it's not always a good idea). In C, if you use any particular synchronization primitives, then your code has a dependency on that particular threading API (POSIX pthreads perhaps, or Windows libraries), even though as you say your code has nothing to do with threading. So you've needlessly excluded some users.

Comment: One option is to provide a thread-safe *version* of your code, for a particular threading API, that's some kind of wrapper to the thread-unsafe version. But usually in C and C++, threading and synchronization is considered a high-level concern. Basic data structures by convention are unsafe, and the user of the structure should synchronize them in the most appropriate way, which might be "not at all", if the instance of your structure is only used by a single application thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that

```
l->locked = TRUE;
```

will happen instantly within a single atomic operation. It might be compiled into several CPU instructions (that depends on CPU architecture, compiler, operating system etc.)

You should use synchronization mechanisms that are provided by your environment. Those are beyond the scope of the C standard.

Comment: What happens if this thread is interrupted while in the middle of this instruction? The other thread would set `l->locked`, then do it stuff, then reset the lock and return, at which point this thread would start again from where it was.

Answer (score 5):

Standard C doesn't "know" anything about threads. Anything threading related as thread themselves, synchronization primitives, atomic operations are not part of the language or the standard library. They are always part of system libraries as POSIX or the Windows API.

Therefore it is not possible to protect your data structure against a race condition when it is used by multiple threads using only standard C.

If an instance of your structure is only used by a single thread, it can be used in a multi-thread scenario as you e.g. don't use static variables inside your functions.

Answer (score 4):

Your code could cause a `race condition.` You should use a mutex for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think Ansi C provides a mutex mechanism... also it doesn't provide a multitheading mechanism as well.

If you want to get a multithreading code which is portable you may chose a primitive set like [posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). Of course this is portable on Unix systems only. So, if you want a suggestion, you should program against some high level library with wraps threads and mutexes on different systems. I think that [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The principle is ok, depending on your platform.
If you have a very simple processor and the resource is shared between two interrupt routines, this might be enough.

You should be wary of race conditions and priority inversion, look it up.